# How to make URL for each tab in a page in sitecore 7.0?

Tags: asp.net, sitecore, sitecore7

I have an application on sitecore 7.0.

I have a sitecore item named as `Item1`. That item's view has 3 tab mainly `Home`, `about` and `contact`. The URL for the item is `/en/Home/Item1`. On page load, `Home` section renders by default. so, i want the URL by default to be `/en/Home/Item1/home`. When the user clicks `about` tab, the page remains same but URL changes to `/en/Home/Item1/about`. The problem is that the URL `/en/Home/Item1/home` itself doesn't exist, so how do i allow Sitecore to just read the URL as `/en/Home/Item1` and ignore everything that is after it or consider it as an argument.

[Refer to this image to get the idea of design of the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OZUvP.png)

Answer (score 0):

Use [ISS rewrite rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module)

Final result will look something like this

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Rewrite to home">
      <match url="^en/Home/Item1/home" />
      <action type="Rewrite" url="/en/Home/Item1?tab=home" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

or like this

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Rewrite Item1">
       <match url="^en/Home/Item1/([_0-9a-z-]+)" />
       <action type="Rewrite" url="/en/Home/Item1?tab={R:1}" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

dependant what you want to do after